# Delete from table A joining on table A in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, delete-row

I am trying to write the following MySQL query in PostgreSQL 8.0 (specifically, using Redshift):

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (
    t1.field   = t2.field AND
    t1.field2  = t2.field2
)
WHERE t1.field > 0
```

PostgreSQL 8.0 does not support `DELETE FROM table USING`. The examples in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-delete.html) say that you can reference columns in other tables in the where clause, but that doesn't work here as I'm joining on the same table I'm deleting from. The other example is a subselect query, but the primary key of the table I'm working with has four columns so I can't see a way to make that work either.

Comment: What error/results are you seeing.  First thing I see that seems wrong with your query is that it should be "DELETE FROM" (removing "t1")

Comment: Yeah sure, that's a mysql query I don't expect it to just work in postgresql. I just haven't been able to find an equivalent in Postgresql 8.0 at all. The syntax for deletes is very minimal.

Comment: BTW: what is `table` ? a keyword ?

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL query is doing what you want? The `LEFT JOIN` seems completely useless.

Comment: @wildplasser `table` is the table name.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yeah, you're right, the left join is useless. Join would be the correct behaviour. I'm migrating code that was written ages ago.

Comment: Why would anyone call his table `table` ?

Comment: You should describe the exact purpose of the query. The broken MySQL query doesn't cut it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sure. The purpose is to delete records from a table  , with a where clause that refers to other rows in the same table. The full, unsimplified use case is that I want to remove records where there is another record in the table with 3 fields matching, and 1 field falls within a range of 60.

Comment: The description is an essential part of the question and should not be hidden in the comments, edit the question and make the example match the text. This also *needs* the table definition. To identify "another record" we need the primary key. We also need to see `NOT NULL` constraints. With 37k XP you should be well aware of the basics here ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the mysql syntax, but you probably want this:

```
DELETE FROM mytablet1
WHERE t1.field > 0
   -- don't need this self-join if {field,field2}
   -- are a candidate key for mytable
   -- (in that case, the exists-subquery would detect _exactly_ the
   -- same tuples as the ones to be deleted, which always succeeds)
-- AND EXISTS (
--     SELECT *
--     FROM mytable t2 
--     WHERE t1.field = t2.field
--     AND t1.field2  = t2.field2
--    )
    ;
```

---

Note: For testing purposes, you can replace the `DELETE` keyword by `SELECT *` or `SELECT COUNT(*)`, and see which rows would be affected by the query.

Comment: I think this could be exactly what I need. Let me confirm!

Answer (score 18):

Amazon Redshift was forked from Postgres 8.0, but is a *very much different beast*. [The manual informs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DELETE.html), that the `USING` clause *is* supported in `DELETE` statements:

Just use the modern form:

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl
USING  tbl t2
WHERE  t2.field  = tbl.field
AND    t2.field2 = tbl.field2
AND    t2.pkey  <> tbl.pkey    -- exclude self-join
AND    tbl.field > 0;
```

This is assuming `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` in your MySQL statement, which would not make any sense. I also added the condition `AND t2.pkey <> t1.pkey`, to make it a useful query. This excludes rows joining itself. `pkey` being the primary key column.

What this query does:
*Delete all rows where at least one **other** row exists in the same table with the same not-null values in `field` and `field2`. All such duplicates are deleted without leaving a single row per set.*

To keep (for example) the row with the smallest `pkey` per set of duplicates, use `t2.pkey < t2.pkey`.

An `EXISTS` semi-join (as @wilplasser already hinted) might be a better choice, especially if multiple rows could be joined (a row can only be deleted once anyway):

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE  field > 0
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   tbl t2
   WHERE  t2.field  = tbl.field
   AND    t2.field2 = tbl.field2
   AND    t2.pkey  <> tbl.pkey 
   );
```

Comment: That gets us close, but it only works if `t1` and `t2` are different. In my case, they are the same. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I intended for `table` to be the table name and `t1`/`t2` to be aliases. Thanks for pointing out the syntax was different I guessed it was the same!

Comment: Funny: the `AND t2.pkey <> t1.pkey` condition still will delete all satisfying tuples (except if no duplicates exist) Maybe you meant `AND t2.pkey < t1.pkey` ??

Comment: @wildplasser: Well, yes. That's the purpose of the query as I guessed it for lack of definition. I added a few lines to clarify.

Comment: We both could be right. (or wrong) the intention of the OP is still totally unclear, at least to me.

Comment: @wildplasser: Strictly speaking, your simplified version is the correct answer. It just doesn't make any sense, so I provided an answer that might make more sense.

Comment: In redshift you are not allowed to alias the target table, ie you must code `DELETE FROM tbl1 USING ...`

Comment: The modern form is an excellent answer. The reason many people like me would do any join is because the table data requirements are not materialised yet i.e. join (insert sub query here) t2 on ... and so on. USING statement is an excellent choice, just need to materialise the table somewhere else beforehand, either a cte, temp or physical table. Thanks.